# $d(x_n,y_n)$ converges to a limit when $x_n, y_n$ are Cauchy sequences

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_n, y_n$ Cauchy sequences.  Is there a way to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n)$ exists without involving the completion of $X$?  Intuitively you have the $x_n$s, and the $y_n$s, each trapped in an open ball, so their distance cannot change wildly.  But it seems surprisingly difficult to prove that the given limit actually exists.

Comment: But these are completely different sequences right?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, why is it upvoted?

Comment: This question makes perfect sense to me.  What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7):

$$d(x_n, y_n) \leq d(x_n, x_m) + d(x_m, y_n) \leq d(x_n, x_m) + d(x_m, y_m) + d(y_m, y_n)$$

so

$$d(x_n, y_n) - d(x_m, y_m) \leq d(x_n, x_m)  + d(y_m, y_n)$$

Similarly, we have

$$d(x_m, y_m) - d(x_n, y_n) \leq d(x_n, x_m)  + d(y_m, y_n)$$

so

$$|d(x_m, y_m) - d(x_n, y_n)| \leq d(x_n, x_m)  + d(y_m, y_n)$$

so $a_n = d(x_n,y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, so its limit exsits

Comment: The conclusion is more or less obvious from the definitions, but the question still doesn't make sense to me. What does "without invoking the completion of X" mean here?

Comment: @SuzuHirose The conclusion is indeed true, but some arguments are needed to prove it. Without invoking the completion of $X$ means we don't argue like $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ so $d(x_n, y_n) \to d(x,y)$

Comment: Since these are Cauchy sequences you cannot argue like that, since that doesn't form a part of the definition of Cauchy sequences. That is unrelated to completion of X.

Comment: You could embed $X$ is its completion, then the Cauchy sequences would converge to their respective unique limits, then argue as Petite did